# How to do constant initialization of all global and local variables in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried passing

```
tf.variables_initializer(tf.constant_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
```

but didn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`tf.variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer) takes in a list of variables instead of initializers. So if you want to initialize variables with constants, the steps you may need to take would be:

1) use `tf.constant_initializer` when constructing the variables, e.g. `v = tf.get_variable(name='v', initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.), shape=(1))`,

2) get the list of variables you want to initialize,

3) set up the init_op, i.e. `init_op = tf.variables_initializer([v1, v2, ...])`,

4) run the init_op with a session.

I'm not saying this is the only way, but it should be a common approach.